# Can someone explain how the recursion works for an inorder BST traversal?

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree, inorder

I realize a code for an inorder traversal would look something like

```
  if left[x] != NULL
    recurse left
    process
  right[x] !=NULL
    recurse right
```

I coded everything up, works fine. I then started to think more and have over-thought the process and now am lost in how the recursion actually works. Because I think that all the way left, the recursion would end because both nodes are null.

If I am all the way left and both right and left nodes are NULL, how does the recursive call bring me back up to the parent node to continue the traversal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like all recursion*, the call stack contains the control for your operations as the recursive calls start to return - program control is returned to the point where your `current_node` pointer is set to the parent that you were examining prior to making the recursive calls.

(* All recursion, unless there's tail-call optimization going on, in which case it is just a loop).

Comment: It all just hit me at once right before you commented. Thank you.